# Trying to pass dropdown selection from HTML to Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu in index.html, and a Flask function in app.py that's supposed to do stuff based on the dropdown selection. But the selection value isn't getting sent to the Flask function.

In index.html:

```
  <form method="POST">
  <select name = "text">
    <option value="Iliad">Iliad</option>
    <option value="Odyssey">Odyssey</option>
  </select>
  </form>
```

In app.py:

```
@app.route("/", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def home():
    selection = request.form.get('text')

    if selection == 'Odyssey':
        # do some stuff
    if selection == 'Iliad':
        # do some stuff

    # some other code
    return render_template("index.html")
```

The "some other code" bit runs fine when I load the page. However, if I then make a selection from the dropdown menu, none of the "do some stuff" code runs, i.e. it's not entering the conditionals.

I've also tried adding "if request.method == 'POST':" right before the two conditionals, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Help?

Comment: I am using request.form['text'] in my own project and that works so maybe try that? Not sure why that would make a difference though.

Comment: @nj1234 I tried that but I get this error message: "werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'text'"

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the form was missing a submit button! I added

```
<button type="submit">Go</button>
```

to the HTML and now it works. Just leaving this here in case other newbies have the same problem.